# Variance matrix with equal diagonal entries in PROC MIXED

Tags: mixed-model, sas

Is it possible to specify a variance matrix for the random effects in PROC MIXED with the only restriction that the diagonal entries are equal ? I took a look in the help and I have not found, but this seems strange because such a variance structure is rather natural in some applications.

(EDIT) Consider for instance such a dataset:

```
> dat
   Subject Dose   y
1        1    A  10
2        1    A  11
3        1    A  12
4        1    B  30
5        1    B  31
6        1    B  32
7        1    C 100
8        1    C 101
9        1    C 102
10       2    A  11
11       2    A  14
12       2    A  13
13       2    B  33
14       2    B  37
15       2    B  36
16       2    C 105
17       2    C 110
18       2    C 109
19       3    A   9
20       3    A  11
21       3    A  12
22       3    B  30
23       3    B  35
24       3    B  32
25       3    C 115
26       3    C 101
27       3    C 102
```

[image: dataplot]

and the following model:

```
PROC MIXED DATA=dat ;
    CLASS SUBJECT DOSE ;
    MODEL y = DOSE ;
    RANDOM DOSE / subject=SUBJECT type=MYMATRIX ;
RUN; QUIT;
```

I want a matrix "MYMATRIX" with the same variance for each level of the DOSE factor, but not a compound symmetry matrix because the correlation between the means of the levels are different.

(EDIT2) The mathematical meaning of this model is the following one. Denoting by $i$ the index for the dose level and by $j$ the index for the subject, one has $$(y_{ijk} | \mu_{ij}) \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu_{ij}, \sigma^2_w), \quad k=1, \ldots, 3 \quad \text{ for all } i,j$$ and $$ \begin{pmatrix} 
\mu_{1j} \\
\mu_{2j} \\
\mu_{3j}  
 \end{pmatrix}
 \sim_{\text{iid}} 
 {\cal N}_3
 \left( 
 \begin{pmatrix} 
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2 \\ 
\mu_3 
 \end{pmatrix}, 
 G
 \right), \quad j=1, \ldots, 3$$
The diagonal entries of the $G$ matrix are the between variances for each level of the dose. I want $G$ to be of the form $$G=\begin{pmatrix} \sigma^2_b & \sigma_{12} & \sigma_{13} \\  \sigma_{12} & \sigma^2_b & \sigma_{23} \\ \sigma_{13} &   \sigma_{23} & \sigma^2_b \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Do you mean you have several random effects and that you assume all of them to have the same variance?

Comment: @ocram I have just added an example

Comment: What's the motivation for doing this? If you constrain the diagonal of the covariance matrix to be the same, the off diagonal is no longer a correlation/covariance anymore.

Comment: You're wrong AdamO. For example the identity matrix is such a matrix. The motivation is that there is a physical interpretation of the equality of the between variances.

Comment: Is there no update to this question? I am having exactly the same problem.

Comment: @user38429 No, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If I do understand your model, you have a random dose effect for each subject:

$$ \gamma = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\gamma_{1A} \\
\gamma_{1B} \\
\gamma_{1C} \\
\gamma_{2A} \\
\gamma_{2B} \\
\gamma_{2C} \\
\gamma_{3A} \\
\gamma_{3B} \\
\gamma_{3C} \\
\end{array}
\right), $$
and $G = \textrm{Var}(\gamma)$ has a block-diagonal structure with identical blocks over subjects:
$$ G = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\star & \star & \star & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\star & \star & \star & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\star & \star & \star & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \star & \star & \star & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \star & \star & \star & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \star & \star & \star & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \star & \star & \star \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \star & \star & \star \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \star & \star & \star 
\end{array}
\right). $$

Now, the `type` option specifies the covariance structure of each block. If you specify `type=vc` (default) then each block will have the form
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\star & \star & \star \\
\star & \star & \star \\
\star & \star & \star 
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma_{_{G}}^{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_{_{G}}^{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sigma_{_{G}}^{2} 
\end{array}
\right), $$
where $\sigma_{_{G}}^{2}$ is the single parameter of $G$ to be estimated. If you specify `type=toep` then
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\star & \star & \star \\
\star & \star & \star \\
\star & \star & \star 
\end{array}
\right) = \sigma_{_{G}}^{2} \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rho_1 & \rho_2 \\
\rho_1 & 1 & \rho_1 \\
\rho_2 & \rho_1 & 1
\end{array}
\right), $$
and now there are three parameters in $G$ to be estimated.

$$$$

If this does not fit your requirement, then you might want to have a look at the `group` option: *all observations having the same level of the group effect have the same covariance parameters*.

Comment: Thank you. In regards to your PS, you're wrong. I will edit my post to make it clearer. The Toeplitz matrix is not appropriate because of $\sigma_{12}=\sigma_{23}$.

Comment: Indeed, the Toeplitz does not fully fit what you want. But is sigma12=sigma23 totally unreasonable? Otherwise, I am afraid you have to go to 'type=un' which is a little bit more general than your G matrix...

Comment: Another motivation for the equality of the diagonal variances is that I assume $y = \log x$ and then taking the exponential of some confidence bounds for $\mu_1-\mu_2$ gives a confidence interval about the ratio of the means of the $x$ response. This is not true without assuming equality of variances.

Comment: Indeed it is not totally unreasonable to assume $\sigma_{12}=\sigma_{23}$. This is what I will do because this is the best available option. But my post is about a way to relax this assumption.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent: I know it is possible to provide your own G matrix to proc mixed, but I am not sure it is possible for that matrix to depend on parameters. So, another possibility is to estimate the variance components in a separate statistical analysis, if possible, and to provide the resulting fully determined matrix to proc mixed...

Comment: Yes but if I specify a G matrix with known parameters this does not yield the correct standard errors and degrees of freedom for the fixed parameters (I think).

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect036.htm

Comment: Thanks. I hope one day I will try GDATA with a simple example. Now I have to advance in my work (with the Toeplitz matrix ;)

Comment: Ok, good work ;-)